# nms formmail - no email validation if not required + separate redirect page

Tags: perl, email-validation, formmail

I have setup [nms formmail](http://nms-cgi.sourceforge.net/) recently on my blog and I made email optional, however I would like to make sure that when it is filled out, an email validation check is run. It looks like nms formmail only offers this check in case the email field is required.

I would like to modify the cgi script using it's own validate_email function and redirect to a "email not valid" page in case the email field is not empty and the field is not valid.

Note that I have added the following code already that takes care of adding a standard email in case the field is empty, so the check should probably come after this line somewhere: `$email = 'empty_email@mydomain.com' unless $email;`

inside this bit of code:

```
sub send_main_email {
  my ($self, $date, $email, $realname) = @_;

  my $mailer = $self->mailer;
  $mailer->newmail($self->name_and_version, $self->{CFG}{postmaster}, @{ $self->{Recipients} });

  $email = 'empty_email@mydomain.com' unless $email;

  $self->send_main_email_header($email, $realname);
  $mailer->print("\n");

  $self->send_main_email_body_header($date);

  $self->send_main_email_print_config;

  $self->send_main_email_fields;

  $self->send_main_email_footer;

  $mailer->endmail;
}
```

I tried doing the following under `empty_email@mydomain.com' unless $email;`:

```
if (validate_email($email) = 0) {
    print $self->cgi_object->redirect($self->{FormConfig}{'bad_email'});
}
```

...but it returned this error: `Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call at (eval 8) line 1062.`

this is the HTML I'm using:

```
<form method=post action="http://mydomain.com/formmail.cgi">
<label for="realname">name (optional)</label><br />
<input type=text name="realname" /><br />
<label for="email">e-mail (optional)</label><br />
<input type=text name="email"/><br />
<label for="text">text (required)</label><br />
<textarea name=text></textarea><br />
<input type=submit value="send">

<input type=hidden name="redirect" value="http://mydomain.com/thank-you.html">
<input type=hidden name="subject" value="Email form submitted">
<input type=hidden name="required" value="text">
<input type=hidden name="missing_fields_redirect" value="http://mydomain.com/missing-field.html">
<input type=hidden name="bad_email" value="http://www.google.com/">
<input type=hidden name="env_report" value="REMOTE_HOST,REMOTE_ADDR,HTTP_USER_AGENT">
<input type=hidden name="sort" value="order:contact,text">
</form>
```

Note that I have no specific knowledge in perl, but I'm pretty fast in picking up new code language, so please bear with me, and try to be as detailed as possible (preferably with example code instead of describing what you think, unless it makes more sense of course).

Answer (score 2):

`if (validate_email($email) = 0)` should be `if ( not validate_email($email) ) {`
or `if ( !validate_email($email) ) {` or `if ( 0 == validate_email($email) ) {` because = is assignment operator and == is numeric-equality operator

that covers the syntax error, all I have time for :) also "valid_email" sounds better read out loud ( if not valid_email foo@example.com then redirect to badmailpage

Comment: tried `( !validate_email($email) )` but getting another error (this one only shows in the logfiles): `Undefined subroutine &CGI::NMS::Script::FormMail::validate_email called at (eval 8) line 1062` although validate_email is defined much earlier in the script. Or can I not call a subroutine inside another subroutine...?

Comment: Add `die __PACKAGE__;` before `sub send_main_email` so you know what to call it (full name) . More on this in [Simple Module Tutorial](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=102347). Or name it `sub Webeno::valid_email` and call it `Webeno::valid_email()`

Comment: I added `die __PACKAGE__;` before `sub send_main_email` and got this error in the log: `AH01215: CGI::NMS::Script::FormMail at (eval 8) line 1055`... `AH01215: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at [name_of_file].cgi line 3285` where `[name_of_file]` is the name of the CGI file on the server. I do not know how to name the subroutine and I do actually want to use the existing one, so how do I do it?

Comment: you can write `sub any::name::you::want { ... }`  ***BUT*** since you report package of `validate_email` as `CGI::NMS::Script::FormMail` and the error message is `Undefined subroutine &CGI::NMS::Script::FormMail::validate_email` you'll have to show the code if you want more/real help -- see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Sorry, your explanation is not very clear. Also note that I have named and linked the original code so it should not be a problem for you to retrieve it... I decided to abandon this question (flagged it appropriately) and just use one field (email) to be validated in my form.